# symfony2 doctrine relationships one-to-one

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, indexing, entity-relationship

I have 2 questions.

My first question comes from [the doc of doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional) what is "exactly" the difference between the one-to-one unidirectional and the one-to-one bidirectional and when to use either of them?

Secondly I have a one-to-one as such

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\PurchaseBundle\Entity\Status", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $status;
```

When i try to save the form i have an error :

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UNIQ_9861B36D6BF700BD'
```

I understood from the doc that I need to do this relationship bidirectional but I dont see why. All I want is to remove the unique and replace it by index.

Thanks

PS : Just in case it might help. I have an entity Purchase which at the start will have a status of 'order_created' and will be updated in back office at different process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer at your first question I'll take an example :
If you have a User related (with a one to one unidirectionnal relation) to a Car. In this case if you have your user you'll be able to find the car he owns. But if you have the car you won't be able to find the User who owns this car. The bidirectionnal permit you to with your object car find your User.

In the first case this code will works :

```
$user->getCar();
```

But this one won't be possible :

```
$car->getUser();
```

The bidirectionnal allow you to execute both of them.

Hope this help to understand the concept.

Comment: Got it then why is it that 2 users cannot have the same car ?

I am starting to think that its not a one-to-one that I need but a many-to-one.

Comment: yes in this case you have to add a oneToMany on your entity car and a onetToOne on your user. (If you want that 2 users can have the same car but one car for each users)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again with this but as am not used with the concept I having trouble to figure out what I need to do.

I have an entity Purchase and an entity Status. There are four status in all. 'Order created' ... 'order complete'. Each purchase has a status of order created when created. If I got it right, I must have a one-to-one on Purchase and a one-to-many on Status.

Right?

Comment: I think the best option for you is to have your entity with an attribute $status and you set 4 constants in your entity. It'll be much lighter for your application, but if you really need to do it the other way go on ;)

[pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/Vjwt7TG6)

But if you want to do the other way it's correct too, just really heavy in my opinion.

Comment: perfect. the constants worked perfectly. I almost forgot constants in php when using symfony. Thanks Your explanations were perfect